# MVC JavaScript get API data and send to controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, fetch-api

How should I get the API data using MVC and send it to the controller?

Here is what I have so far:

```
"use strict";

const appData = (() => {
  return {
    fetchJSON: url => {
      fetch(url).then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log(response.status);
          return;
        }
        response.json().then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          //Send data to controller
        });
      });
    }
  };
})();

const appUI = (() => {
  
  return {
  };
})();

const appController = ((appData, appUI) => {
  //Get data from appData.fetchJSON()

  return {
    init: () => {
      console.log("Application Initialized...");
      appData.fetchJSON("./data.json");
    }
  };
})(appData, appUI);

appController.init();
```

The idea is to use the data from the API to populate some elements on the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async` function to make a request and then return the resulting data. Inside `init` function you can `await` the result of call to `fetchJSON` function and then you can pass that data to `appUI`

### Edit

To populate views on a button click, you can store the data in `appData` and when button is clicked, you can get data from `appData` and populate the views.

See example below

```js
const appData = (() => {
  const dataStore = {};
  
  const fetchJSON = async (url) => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        return await response.json();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
  };
  
  return { dataStore, fetchJSON };
})();

const appUI = ((appData) => {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    populateViews(appData.dataStore.data);
  });
  
  const populateViews = (data) => {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    const post = `
        <div>
          <p><strong>Post ID:</strong> ${data.id}</p>
          <p><strong>Title</strong></p>
          <p>${data.title}</p>
          <p><strong>Body</strong></p>
          <p>${data.body}</p>
        </div>
    `;
    body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', post);
  };
  
  return { btn };
})(appData);

const appController = ((appData, appUI) => {
  const init = async () => {
      console.log("Application Initialized...");
      const data = await appData.fetchJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
      appData.dataStore.data = data;
      
      // enable button after data has been saved
      appUI.btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  };
  
  return { init };
})(appData, appUI);

appController.init();
```

```css
button {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  background: blueviolet;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:disabled {
  background: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" disabled>Fetch Data</button>
```

Comment: Great answer. I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` on `const data = await appData.fetchJSON("")`. I did add `async` on `fetchURL` function. Why do you think that is?

Comment: as the error message is telling you, you can only use `await` keyword inside `async` function. You are using `await` keyword inside 2 functions, `fetchJSON` and `init`. Make sure both are `async` functions. You probably didn't make `init` function `async`

Comment: Spot on @yousaf. I have a part two for the question, I oversimplified my situation and got stuck again? Basically, I need to call `appUI.populateViews()` from a button click as well. I am struggling to pass the `data` though. should I edit the question with part 2?